# Doctrine and Symfony autogenerate db table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I wrote this below code manually and after I execute command in a shell to create the db table but in db was created only the empty table (name="lcl_user") without columns.

```
namespace Stefano\ZulliBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Stefano\ZulliBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="lcl_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $facebook_id;

/** @ORM\Column(name="facebook_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $facebook_access_token;

/** @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $google_id;

/** @ORM\Column(name="google_access_token", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
protected $google_access_token;


//YOU CAN ADD MORE CODE HERE !
}
```

and the command shell I executed is:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: is the ZulliBundle registered in your `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Yes . . @Chausser there is this line:new Stefano\ZulliBundle\StefanoZulliBundle(),

Comment: and you dont get any errors when running the command?

Comment: It doesnt even generate the ID column?

Comment: Did you run validate-schema, generate-proxies, and dump-sql? If so, is everything showing up fine?